# Value of the variable changes despite me assigning it

Tags: java, android

So I have a activity in which is passes an intent to start another activity. Along with that intent, I have included a boolean value so that that value gets passed to the activity I want to open. My problem is this, I have used Log.D to display whether the boolean is true or false in relevant places throughout my activity. So far its what I am expecting but then when I use the value on an onClick method, it changes to false for some reason... This is where it changes:

```
Log.d("hints", "Value of hints, GameActivity above keypadhash: " + hints);
    keypadHash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //if reach last question then output score
            if (questionCounter < 10) {
                Log.d("hints", "Value of hints, GameActivity onClick(): " + hints); 
                if (hints == false) {
```

On the first Log.d it prints out `D/hints: Value of hints, GameActivity above keypadhash: true` but on the second Log.d it prints out: `D/hints: Value of hints, GameActivity onClick(): false` And it won't execute the else statement after the if statement since it fulfils the condition when its not supposed to.

I have no idea how its changing its value in a matter of a couple of lines code. the boolean variable is a global variable.

EDIT = Found out my problem. Turns out my app was reading a previous saved state in which it was restoring the values then

Comment: please provide the full code for the onClick method

Comment: you must be modifying it someWhere. provide full code.

Comment: There is no such thing as "a global variable" in Java. If you struggle even to describe the problem and tell us what "hints" is, you have very little chance of grasping Android's lifecycle. Rest assured, that variables and attributes don't change values by themselves, ever.

Comment: @Carmine I have provided the full code

Comment: @TarikhChouhan as there is no a single assignment to your variable `hints`, I can say the following. First of all, the `hints` is not a `global`, it is a `class variable` . And by default, the boolean class variables are assigned to `false`. So maybe you just need to trace your code execution order, I guess it's default by value, and then assign to true, but you just see that in reversed order as your listeners are not working in linear order.

Comment: @Carmine Ive defined the  boolean hints variable at the top of this class. And then on the onCreate method i have it assigned a value according to what was passed in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

onClick is not called immediately - it is a listener, so it is only called when the onClick event is fired. So even though these lines of code are proximate, they do not execute that closely. Somewhere else between what you've provided and when the user clicks your global variable is being altered.

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem. You should added it in the comment.